# Not getting custom error message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using following code in Laravel for custom error message. But some how i am not getting custom error message.

```
$rules = [
    '12' => 'email',
];

$messages = [
    '12.email' => 'address must be valid email address.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($requestData, $rules, $messages);
```

When i print `echo '<pre>';print_r($validator->errors());die;` it does not show proper custom message.

Comment: show your form?? or dd($requestData)

Comment: Does it show the default error message instead or no message at all?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes it shows default message like 'The 0 must be a valid email address' .

Comment: update your question with your form code

Comment: @Sohel0415 dd($requestData) is array:15 [
  0 => "xx"
  1 => "xxx"
  2 => "xx"
  3 => "xxx"
  4 => "xx"
  5 => "xxx"
  6 => "xxx"
  7 => "xxx"
  8 => "xxx"
  9 => "xxx"
  10 => "xxx"
  11 => "xxx"
  12 => ""
  13 => "xxx"
  14 => "xxx"
 ]

Comment: Can you also show the complete code as well? This code on its own does not reproduce the issue correctly. There seems to be a laravel inability to deal with non-continuous numeric indices when it comes to rules but if you actually have continuous indices you would not see the issue. If you have rules and messages from 0 to 14 (no gaps) then it would work but would break otherwise

Comment: i would suggest that you update your question with full controller code and view code

Comment: @SaurabhParekh 12 is field name ??

Comment: @DeadManAlive Yes it is key of my array. I am not having form field array. I have my own array that i need to validate with laravel validator.

Answer (score 1):

I think laravel is not allowing to have integer input parameters

when i do this

```
    $rules = [
        '12-test' => 'required|email',
    ];

    $messages = [
        '12-test.required' => 'address must be valid email address.',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), $rules, $messages );
    dd($validator->errors());
```

it gives me proper errors for input field '12-test'
[image]